# Should I use JOIN or UNION for this MYSQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, join, union

I am trying to display data from two different tables ordered by the time the data was created.

Here are the 2 tables I am pulling data from:

active_projects

```
+------------+------------+---------+-------+-------------+
| project_id | ts_created | user_id | title | description |
+------------+------------+---------+-------+-------------+
```

likes

```
+---------+------------+------------+
| user_id | project_id | ts_created |
+---------+------------+------------+
```

The desired result is all of the data retrieved from these columns displayed properly, ordered by this column:

```
+------------+
| ts_created |
+------------+
```

This is the query that I am currently using:

```
$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM (SELECT project_id AS ppid, 
                     ts_created AS pts,
                     user_id AS puid,
                     title AS ptitle,
                     description AS pdesc
              FROM active_projects 
              WHERE user_id = 12)
        UNION
             (SELECT id AS lid, 
                     user_id AS luid,
                     project_id AS lpid,
                     ts_created AS lts
              FROM likes 
              WHERE user_id = 12)";
```

But, it's not working the way I want to. I've been trying to debug what's going on but right now it's just saying that it's not actually retrieving any of the data.

I have been researching JOIN and UNION but am not sure which one I should be using for this query. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
The query is now displaying properly using @Samuel's answer. But, now the results are being displayed 3 times per row.
I am doing this at the end of the query:

```
$act = mysql_query($sql);
```

Then, when I echo out the results I am using a while loop likes this:

```
while ($t = mysql_fetch_row($act)) {
    echo $t[1];
}
```

Any ideas as to why each row is being displayed 3 times?

Comment: Can you please tell us your desired result ?How we will know the reason for your unsatisfaction

Comment: If you want to get likes FOR active projects, then use JOIN. If you want to get likes AND active projects, then you need UNION. What do you want?

Comment: UNION: _Selected columns listed in corresponding positions of each SELECT statement should have the same data type._

Comment: Never use nested select queries. Its time consuming. Use JOINS instead.

Comment: I want to get active projects AND likes. But, @Samuel's answer worked for me using JOIN. Still not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is quite awful in terms of runtime performance and it does not produce the result you wish. 
Probably more useful:

```
$sql = "
    SELECT * FROM active_projects
    LEFT JOIN likes ON (active_projects.user_id = likes.user_id)
    WHERE user_id = 12";
```

Untested, but something like that is what you need.
This should create a result of all entries from active_project for the user_id 12 left joined with the table likes.

Comment: This is working pretty well. Had to tweak a couple things but I have the desired result now. Except for the fact that everything is being displayed 3 times. I'm running the query through a while loop. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are the triple sets displayed per query or why are you looping it?

Comment: Yes, the triple sets are being displayed per query.

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly. Most of the rows have common names but I am using the row number to echo out the data. I don't see a reason why the results are being duplicated 3 times. Check my edited question to see how I am displaying the results.

Comment: What I mean: The 3 identical rows, is there every column identical? Is it possible that they differ slightly in some of the columns?
How ever you can use GROUP BY (user_id), this should result in no redundant rows but does probably not fix the cause why they are duplicated

Comment: No, only 2 of the columns are identical. The third one is `TIMESTAMP`, so that will differ in every column. I messed around with `GROUP BY` a little bit and got varied results, just not the one i'm looking for. However, whenever I used `GROUP BY` it removed the duplicate results.

Comment: I believe I got it working. I just changed the `ON` statement from `ON(active_projects.user_id=likes.user_id)` to `ON(active_projects.project_id=likes.project_id)`. This removed the duplicated results. Now I am trying to order all the results by the common `ts_created` column. Btw, I didn't end up using `GROUP BY`.

Comment: My bad, of course you are right. The join statement should be on the project_id! Great that you solved it without the GROUP BY. The ordering is done by ORDER BY (just in case you did not know).

Answer (score 0):

First your query has a problem. You can't do 
`select * from (select ...)`. 
there should be 'where' clause before calling another sub query.

You should use join instead of union as union is used to show results for tables with the same column names/types (aliases) while join uses a foreign key from the other table to show a 'joined' output.

Do the following:

```
SELECT A.project_id AS ppid, 
       A.ts_created AS pts,
       A.user_id AS puid,
       A.title AS ptitle,
       A.description AS pdesc,
       B.id AS lid, 
       B.user_id AS luid,
       B.project_id AS lpid,
       B.ts_created AS lts
FROM active_projects A
LEFT JOIN likes B ON
       A.user_id = B.user_id
WHERE A.user_id = 12 ORDER BY B.ts_created;
```

Actually, you can choose between, RIGHT JOIN and LEFT JOIN.

Comment: This didn't work for me. For some reason it wasn't liking the aliases added to the table names.